# IIS 6 404 for default document

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I have an ASP.NET website deployed on IIS 6. I have several folders in my app containing handlers like log.ashx, default.ashx and so on.

I have default document configured in IIS, so that I can type www.mydomain.com/tools in the browser, and I will get the /tools/default.ashx.

IIS gives me 404 all the time, which is my problem. I also have the aspnet_isapi.dll configured as a wildcard handler.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the default document in IIS just tells IIS to look for a document with that name in the requested folder, so if /tools/default.ashx doesn't exist on the server, then you will indeed get a 404.

You need to declare handlers in the web.config - and this article http://dotnetperls.com/Content/ASHX-Handler.aspx runs you through how you could set something similar up using the urlMappings part of the web.config.

Comment: Do you really think that I post a question here without knowing that default.ashx actually exists in the folder? :)

Comment: To be honest, no, I did misread that part of your question. However, I created a simple site, added default.ashx to the list of documents in IIS, and created a folder called tools with a "GeneralHandler" called default.ashx in it, and that worked as expected, calling /tools displayed handler :(